# How to check if Mono<Void> was actually called?

Tags: java, functional-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming (and I've read a bunch of similar SO questions). In my current pet-project, I've run into the following problem (I'm providing a pseudo code for a scenario in question).

It concerns filtering `Mono<Object>`, and then determining if `Mono<Void>` was called.
In the example below:

1. I create `Mono<String>` from input
2. filter, if input `String resource` is suitable for my method.
3. flat map my `Mono<String>` to long-running `Mono<Void>`. It changes some inner system properties but doesn't return anything.
4. if `service.loadSmth` was executed and completed successfully, I want to call `serviceContinueWork.doSmthElse()`

```java
public Mono<Void> execute(String resource) {
    return Mono.just(resource) //Mono<String>
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) //Mono<String>
            .filter(msg -> msg.startsWith("http://")) //filtering the Mono<String>
            .flatMap(msg -> service.loadSmth(msg)) //flat map to Mono<Void>
            .doOnSuccess(command -> serviceContinueWork.doSmthElse()) //!!! executed always :(
            .doOnError(t -> log.error("service#loadSmth error: {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(t)))
            .then();
}
```

Hovewer, `doOnSuccess` is called regardless if a string was filtered or not. An empty Mono is considered successfully terminated, as I understand it.

What is the pattern for such a situation? (When we want to determine if `Mono<Void>` was called - `doOnNext` and `doOnSuccess` are not suitable.)

From what I understand, I can always switch to `service.loadSmth(msg)` returning `Mono<Boolean>` - then `doOnNext` instead of `doOnSuccess` will work just fine.

However, it seems that there should be some way to distinguish between these cases without unnecessary signature changing. I need to know if a method has been called "from outside" - in external calling code.
Like, I wouldn't make a 'void doSmth()' method return boolean, just to know if it has been called (in a usual, non reactive/non functional cases).

Will be grateful for any advice/links.

Comment: You could put the doOnSuccess call inside the flatMap: `flatMap(msg -> service.loadSmth(msg).doOnSuccess(...))`

Comment: @MartinTarjányi yeah, it'll work. Just today thought about it, when stumbled on this exact case with optionals. I just struggle with carrying streams and optionals API onto reactive for some reason. thanks!

Comment: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` this is also not needed, you cant put a `null`in a `Mono`so this `Mono.just(null)` will produce an error. So if you want to do a null check you need to do it before.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer from @MartinTarjányi comment. The pseudocode that works for me:

```java
public Mono<Void> execute(String resource) {
    return Mono.just(resource) 
            .filter(Objects::nonNull) 
            .filter(msg -> msg.startsWith("http://")) 
            .flatMap(msg -> service
                    .loadSmth(msg)
                    .onSuccess((v) -> serviceContinueWork.doSmthElse()))
            .doOnError(t -> log.error("service#loadSmth error: {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(t)))
            .then();
}
```